# SQL query that will add a new row with values from another table

Tags: mysql

i need to write query that will insert a new row into cms_objects_channels but only within given category that is in WHERE clause , but VALUES need to be

- id_objects has to be equal to ID from subquery
- id_channels must be 8 ( static so it will be easy)
- contract_date has to be +6 months from today
- contract_amount has to be 1000 (static)
- params is little tricky because its have to be "hotel_id=id_objects" like "hotel_id=123"
- status has to be "new" (static)
- hotel_id has to be same as id_objects
- active has to be set to 1 (static)

I wrote somthing like this but it doesnt work , VALUES are only to help visualize

```
INSERT INTO hotres_panel.cms_objects_channels (  id_objects 
                                                ,id_channels 
                                                ,contract_date 
                                                ,contract_amount 
                                                ,params 
                                                ,status 
                                                ,hotel_id  
                                                ,active ) 
WHERE id_objects IN
( SELECT id 
  FROM hotres_panel.cms_objects where ( category_id = 175 OR 176 OR 217 OR 180 OR 178 OR 218 OR 196) 
  AND (active = 1) AND (test = 0) 
  AND contract_date >= CONCAT(CURDATE())) 
  VALUES ( '961', '8', '2022-08-20', '199','hotel_id=123' 'new', '961', '1');
```

Comment: INSERT .. VALUES does not allow WHERE clause, use INSERT .. SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query is to give you a hint , you can modify based on your needs.
Based on:

> I wrote somthing like this but it doesnt work , VALUES are only to
> help visualize

To build a dinamic query you need to select all the columns that you are using in your insert statement.  As @Akina mentioned in the comments

> INSERT .. VALUES does not allow WHERE clause, you should use INSERT ..
> SELECT.

```
    INSERT INTO hotres_panel.cms_objects_channels (  id_objects 
                                                ,id_channels 
                                                ,contract_date 
                                                ,contract_amount 
                                                ,params 
                                                ,status 
                                                ,hotel_id  
                                                ,active ) 

SELECT   a.id_objects 
        ,'8' 
        ,curdate()+INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
        ,1000
        ,concat_ws(' ' ,'hotel_id=',a.id_objects)
        ,'new' 
        ,a.id_objects
        ,'1'  

FROM  (

     SELECT id as id_objects 
     FROM  cms_objects 
     WHERE id IN
     (   SELECT id  
         FROM hotres_panel.cms_objects where ( category_id = 175 OR 176 OR 217 OR 180 OR 178 OR 218 OR 196) 
         AND (active = 1) AND (test = 0) 
         AND contract_date >= CONCAT(CURDATE())  
      ) as a ;
```

Comment: i dont exactly know from that "a." comes from , can you explain?

Comment: `a` is just an alias used from me , you can use any aliases you want. When you use subqueries you must use aliases. To be more precise you have to provide table description and some datas or check my answer here if it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616640/insert-into-a-table-from-multiple-tablemysql/69616985#69616985

Comment: In your question you mention `961` as `id_objects` , you have to make the select query with the right condition to give 961 as result

Comment: 961 is only one object that need to have new record , i have like 1200 more id_objects that need to have that new record

Comment: i dont really know what to do in this "SELECT ---all the colums..." can you give some little hint?

Comment: I edit the answer i hope it help you understand, but if you can create a fiddle or give some details it would be better

Comment: Ok it works , but i forgot about one thing , some records will have duplicates , it is possible to write only Unique rows at cms_objects_channels?

Comment: @buhh1231 what do you mean by unique rows? I think you should use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`. Try and let me know

Comment: It gives me an error Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'id_objects' in 'field list'

Comment: @buhh1231 try now if it works

Comment: Now it goes Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.params' in 'field list'

Comment: @buhh1231 now it should be ok

Comment: Ok it works nicely , but it adds rows to records when it should not . Can it work like that if it sees that row has record with id_channels =8 it will skip it?

Comment: @buhh1231 yes you can add another condition when you exclude the `id_channels =8` after `AND contract_date >= CONCAT(CURDATE())`. If it helped you please do not forget to upvote and mark as accepted

Comment: Of course , thanks bro its working like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO hotres_panel.cms_objects_channels (id_objects, id_channels, contract_date, contract_amount, params, status, hotel_id, active) 
SELECT 961, 8, '2022-08-20', 199,'hotel_id=123', 'new', 961, 1
WHERE 961 IN ( SELECT id 
               FROM hotres_panel.cms_objects 
               where category_id IN (175, 176, 217, 180, 178, 218, 196) 
                 AND active = 1 
                 AND test = 0
                 AND contract_date >= CONCAT(CURDATE()) ) 
;
```

Comment: It cant be like that because its static

Comment: @buhh1231 WHAT is static? Edit your question, add a fiddle with sample source data and show desired data state for this fiddle.

Comment: I mean that i need to add new row to every record with id that subquery returns

Comment: @buhh1231 Use your subquery as SELECT part of INSERT .. SELECT.

Comment: Can you show it on code? Doesnt have to be finished code , it will be easier for me because im a beginner in this